# How to get a string between two special characters using Shell?

Tags: shell, string

I want to get a string between two special characters. For example,

```
/home/oracle/ggs/text.ext
```

I want **oracle/ggs** in the above string.

How can I do this using bash?

Comment: `echo oracle/ggs` will answer your question. Please clarify what the requirement are. Is that characters 7 to 16? From the 2nd to 4th `/`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was just as confused as you were...Well, for a starter: when I want a string *between two special characters* I usually assume that there will be __no special character of the same kind in between__! So to say, parsing the (silly) string `&%asdf$Chris$fdsa?#` for "the string between the `$`" would clearly mean that the result is `Chris` and, as visible, there is no other `$` sign in between. How else could the parser decide?? -- This question ought to be flagged as "too specific" as the technique described in the answers may not be needed elsewhere but in this lone case.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ expr /home/oracle/ggs/text.ext : '/home/\(.*\)/'
oracle/ggs
```

That returns the part after `/home/` and before the last `/`.

Other possible approaches that will fulfil your requirements:

```
$ echo /home/oracle/ggs/text.ext | cut -d/ -f3,4
oracle/ggs
$ echo /home/oracle/ggs/text.ext | cut -c 7-16
oracle/ggs
$ echo oracle/ggs
oracle/ggs
```

Comment: I got what I need thanks. >mysql_str=/home/oracle/ext/ggs/text.ext
> path_str=`echo ${mysql_str}| cut -f 2 -d '/'`
> expr ${mysql_str} : '/'${path_str}'/\(.*\)/'
oracle/ext/ggs
> echo $path_str
home

Answer (score 3):

For this particular example, you can use `awk`:

```
echo "$string" | awk -F '/' '{printf "%s%s%s\n" ,$2,FS,$3}'
```

The same in Perl:

```
echo "$string" | perl -lanF '/' -E '$,="/";say @F[1,2]'
```

Comment: oracle@ipt:> echo $x | awk -F '/' '{printf "%s%s%s\n" ,$3,FS,$4}'
oracle/ggs
I want to get the $4 dynamically any suggestions please?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Can you please explain why the quotes are needed here? Won't `echo` be happy with any number of arguments?

Comment: Leaving a variable unquoted in list context is the split+glob operator (the variable is split into words and each word is subject to globbing), that's independent of `echo`. Try with `string='*  *'` for instance. Or with `string=/home/oracle/ggs/text.ext` where IFS is `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Bash

```
IFS=/ read -ra a <<<'/home/oracle/ggs/text.ext' && 
(IFS=/; printf '%s\n' "${a[*]:2:2}") 
oracle/ggs
```